# 'Attribute Error/ function' object has no attribute 'objects' in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to login but getting this error `'function' object has no attribute 'objects'`, here is my view function,

```py
def login(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']

        if register.objects.filter(email=email,password=password).exists(): // Error at this line


            request.session['login'] = email


            return render(request,'user_dashboard.html',)
            messages.info(request,'Login Success.....!')

        else:
            messages.warning(request,'Invalid Credentials....!')
            return redirect('/login')

    else:
        return render(request,'login.html',)
```

The database contains valid credentials, please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is `register`?  You're trying to use it like its a database model, but actually it's a function.

Answer (score 0):

If `Register` is a database model (note that it would normally be declared with a capital letter), then `Register.objects.all()` is the way to access all the objects. So your code could be:

```
if Register.objects.all().filter(email=email,password=password).exists():
```

Comment: Perhaps your code should be referencing the `User` model rather than `register`?Otherwise you will need to share more code and the exception traceback.